# Combox nested within another Combobox

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

Using wxPython, is it possible to nest a combobox inside other combobox in a similar way to how submenus are nested within menus? I need something similar for a wx.Combobox or a wx.Choice.

Or is there any widget with which this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are some possibilities:

```
wx.lib.combotreebox.ComboTreeBox
wx.combo.OwnerDrawnComboBox 
# possibly also:
wx.lib.popupctl
```

You might also use a button (or some control) to invoke a PopupMenu. It may be confusing for the user though, and you might get into trouble when trying to position the Popup menu correctly. Generally speaking, I advice not to be too creative when making UI.

Have you seen wxpython demo?  It is a nice showcase of all possible widgets. You can obtain it from here: https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try it.